# How to integrate Nodejs running on AWS EC2 and static Angularjs content on AWS S3?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services

I have a Nodejs and Angularjs application running on a single AWS EC2 instance. The code structure of the application is as follows :

[Code Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XML91.png)

Currently, when a user makes the first call to the application, the call is handled by nodejs express framework and the call is directed to the index.html page within angular static directory, using the following code in server/server.js file

```
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../web/dist/index.html'));
```

From index.html, various static components (JS, HTML, CSS etc) are invoked and all angularjs controllers / services make a call back to nodejs API for fulfilling user request.

This arrangement works fine in single instance. Now I want to move the angular static content (i.e. web directory to AWS S3). In doing so, do I have to change the following code in server.js to :

```
res.sendFile(path.resolve('**AWS S3 URL** +/web/dist/index.html'));
```

as my static files have now moved to AWS S3. Also, in doing so I have to modify all angular controllers and service to use absolute path to Nodejs API call. This means making lots of changes and introducing deployment configuration (which we have to anyways at a later date for flexibility).

Another approach that we can take is move index.html from web to server folder by making the following changes in server/server.js :

```
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../server/index.html'));
```

then add the following code in server.js to handle redirects for static contents from Nodejs to S3 , something like this :

```
app.get('/assets/*', function(req, res){
    var requestURL = req.url;
    var redirectedURL = <<**Remote S3 base URL**>> + requestURL;
    res.redirect(redirectedURL);
});
```

However, the concern is there will be lots of redirects and I am wondering, if that is a good design? I have read that search engines do not like applications with lots of redirects (HTTP 301, 304) and rank those pages lower. Hence I am trying to find out what is the best practice when deploying nodejs on AWS EC2 and static angularjs contents on S3. Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: There isn't any need for redirects. You should serve your static web content directly from S3 which is achieved by using S3 URLs for your resources. This will also reduce the load on your server.

Comment: Are you suggesting that index.html (within S3) should be accessed directly through the browser ,rather than through nodejs forwarding the call to index.html, and also update all angular controllers in S3 , with absolute NodejS API URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access your content from s3 by adding s3 urls of your files in to your index.html.

And if you want to serve **index.html** as well from s3 then you have to redirect index.html one to s3 and all other you can directly load in to browser from s3.

If you really want to serve public content fast i would suggest using **cloudfront** is an option where you can serve all your public content directly from cloudfront without coming to your node server and all api calls would come to your node server. But yes it depends upon the architecture of your application.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your response. Yes, ultimately the goal is to use cloudfront as CDN.